# Den Substantiv (AKK) -(e)n

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Wieso ist **-en** in folgendem Fall nötig? (Warum ist **den Student** nicht richtig?)

> Zwei Freunde besuchen **den Studenten**.

Gibt es Regeln für die Fälle, wo "**den Substantiv (AKK) -(e)n**" nötig ist?

Comment: Der Akkusativ von *[der Student](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Student)* ist *den Studenten*. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, was Deine Frage ist.

Comment: Wieso ist es **den Studenten** und nicht **den Student**. Warum braucht man ein -n?

Comment: *n-Stämmen, schwäche Deklination* googlen. Jedoch ist mir nicht deutlich ob du einen Ursprung für die Regel willst, oder die Regel selbst.

Comment: Nee :), z.B. findet Google sicherlich [diese Seite](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#W1:_-.28e.29n_.28m..2Fn..29).

Comment: @c.p. ich will die Regel slbst, und mit deine zweite suche "n-Stämmen, schwäche Deklination" habe ich bessere Ergebnisse bekommt. Danke.

Comment: @c.p. wenn du ein Antwort aus deine Kommentaren machst, werde ich es als die richtige Antwort markieren.

Comment: "Den Student" (viel öfter noch *dem* Student) hört man immer wieder... nur halt nicht unter Studenten ;). Wenn man sich die Liste ansieht, bemerkt man, dass die meisten Wörter griechischen/lateinischen Ursprungs sind - das könnte evtl. eine Erklärung sein.

Comment: @Carlster Im verlinkten Artikel Wikipedias heißt es »(Als Beispiel diene die gotische Deklinationsreihe „hraba – hrabins – hrabin – hraban – hrabans – hrabane – hrabam – hrabans“: der ersten Form „hraba“ entspricht im Neuhochdeutschen „Rabe“, alle anderen Formen erscheinen vereinfacht zu „Raben“).«

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wenn ein Wort auf »-ent«, »-and« oder »-ant« endet, dann endet der Akkusativ auf »-enten«, »-anden« bzw. »-anten«.

> Der Student lernt. Ich sehe den Studenten.
>   Der Ministrant dient. Ich begrüße den Ministranten.
>   Der Komödiant macht Witze. Ich lache über den Komödianten.
>   Der Doktorand forscht. Ich bewundere den Doktoranden.

Außerdem:

> -at: der Kandidat – den Kandidaten
>   -et: der Athlet – den Athleten
>   -ist: der Journalist – den Journalisten
>   -oge: der Pädagoge – den Pädagogen
>   -nom: der Ökonom – den Ökonomen
>   -soph: der Philosoph – den Philosophen
>   -graf: der Fotograf – den Fotografen

Comment: Fast. Auffällig ist, dass alle deine Beispiele männlich sind. Das hat einen Grund, denn für alle anderen Nomen stimmt deine Aussage nicht. "Ich sehe das Appartment - Ich nehme das Medikament - Ich lehne mich an die Wand - Ich pflanze die Saat". – Stichwort: N-Deklination

Comment: Auch *-graph* etwa in [Paragraph](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Paragraph), aber ich glaube man versteht, dass es ist der Klang am Ende, was entscheidend für die Beugung sein könnte (also `-graf` ist schon da).

Comment: Neulich habe ich eine Ausnahme gefunden: *Element*.  Das ist nicht mit `-en` zu deklinieren.

Comment: Element (das) ist keine Ausnahme, sondern normal. Bei Neutra ist Nominativ und Akkusativ gleicn, im Singular wie im Plural. "das Element, Nom/Akk, Plural: die Elemente, Nom/Akk.